# ASP.NET MVC3: Why remote validation with RemoteAttribute works only on client side?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I am trying to implement remote validation with the new RemoteAttribute, as describe in the following MSDN article [How to: Implement Remote Validation in ASP.NET MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808%28VS.98%29.aspx).

Client side validation works fine, but when I submit, validation does not work anymore and data is stored into db...

I must necessary implement a server side validation too, or I am not doing all the necessary to prevent the submit?

Answer (score 2):

That's how the Remote validation is designed. It sends an AJAX request to a controller action in order to perform some validations and if those validations fail, prevent the from submitting.

You are correct into thinking that you should perform the same validation once the form is submitted because the user can disable javascript and be able to submit without any client validation being performed. So for example you could externalize this validation logic into a separate method which you would call from the controller action used for remote validation and from your POST action once the form is submitted.

Here are significant parts of my code:

**MODEL**

```
[Remote("CheckEsistenzaTicket", "Validation")]
public string TicketHD { get; set; }
```

**VALIDATION CONTROLLER**

```
[OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public class ValidationController : Controller
    {
        private ITManagerRepository tmanagerRepository;

        public ValidationController()
        {
            this.tmanagerRepository = new TManagerRepository(new TManagerContext());
        }

        public JsonResult CheckEsistenzaTicket(string TicketHD)
        {
            if (!tmanagerRepository.chkTicketExists(TicketHD))
                return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            string esiste = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                "Il ticket {0} risulta già caricato!", TicketHD);

            return Json(esiste, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
    }
```

**VIEW**

```
<div class="editor-field">
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TicketHD)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TicketHD)
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Darin Dimitrov. I would implement a validation logic server side too.

**But just another question**: how MVC3 'standard' validation works?
I set other attribute rules on my model, as [Required], [MaxLength], etc...why for these rules, when I submit, I get validation errors, while for my Remote validation I do not have the same behavior?
Does exist a way to make such validation work for the Remote attribute too?
Thank you!

Comment: @Larry, validation attributes all derive from `ValidationAttribute`. The default model binder invokes validation when it tries to bind the action arguments from the request values. So all the IsValid methods are invoked on data annotations including the RemoteAttribute. Except that, here's how the IsValid method is implemented for this attribute: `public override bool IsValid(object value) { return true; }`. Now you understand why it does not validate anything on the server. If you want to perform the validation you could derive from it and override this method.

Comment: thanks again. I am new in programming. Could you better explain me how I can derive the method in my case?
I put some significant parts of my code inside original question, THX

Comment: @Larry, you derive from `RemoteAttribute` and override the `IsValid` method. If this doesn't make sense to you, you should probably take some time to learn basic OOP and .NET before jumping into ASP.NET MVC.